# Pattern for multiple types from GraphQL Union

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am learning about Interfaces and Unions in GraphQL (using Apollo Server) and am wondering about something. Using documentation examples, https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/#union-type, how would I return a result which could return authors and books?

My understanding is that you can only return one object type. If a search result contains and array of both books and authors, how is such a result returned? Can things be structured for this case? I have noticed that `__resolveType` does not work on an array and can only return a single result (it would return the type for all the objects in the array, not each object in array).

### GraphQL TypeDef

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql`
  union Result = Book | Author

  type Book {
    title: String
  }

  type Author {
    name: String
  }

  type Query {
    search: [Result]
  }
`;
```

### Resolver

```
const resolvers = {
  Result: {
    __resolveType(obj, context, info){
      console.log(obj);
      if(obj.name){
        return 'Author';
      }

      if(obj.title){
        return 'Book';
      }

      return null;
    },
  },
  Query: {
    search: () => { ... }
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`)
});
```

The actual GraphQL query may look something like this and consider the search result is both books and authors:

```
{
  search(contains: "") {
    ... on Book {
      title
    }
    ... on Author {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

When run, `__resolveType(obj, context, info){`, `obj` is:

```
[{ title: 'A' }, { title: 'B' }, { name: 'C' }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only two ways that would happen:

1. The `search` field's type is not actually a list (i.e. it's `Result` instead of `[Result]` as shown in the code above.
2. Your resolver for the `search` field is returning an array of an array of objects: `return [[{ title: 'A' }, { title: 'B' }, { name: 'C' }]]`

Comment: I output the result via `console.log(obj)` and get `[{ title: 'A' }, { title: 'B' }, { name: 'C' }]`

Comment: Thank you Daniel (again ) I found the issue in my schema. In the `TypeDef`, above where it is, `search: [Result]`, mine was basically, `search: Result` so it wasn't treating as an array but a whole object. Glad you hung in there with me!